# "I know you are" as a response to introduction

Tags: conversation

I was watching a movie and noticed this sentence used as a response from a person introducing himself/herself. This is quite odd for me as a non-native speaker of the language.

Example:

*Setting:* In a bar

*Scenario:* **Person A** is friends with **Person B**. **Person A** introduces **Person C** to **Person B**.

> Person C: Hi, I'm Jane.
>
> Person B: I know you are. * smiles *

As a receiver of the response (Person C), what would my reaction be? Or how do I take this kind of response?

As Person B, what are my intentions for saying this response?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about social interaction, not about language.

Comment: @ColinFine: I know you are. ;-)

Comment: *I know you are, but what am I?* -  Pee Wee Herman

Comment: Your reputation has preceded you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cheeky, slightly rude response to Person C's introduction, indicating that B already knows who C is. For example, B could be an old friend that C has forgotten.

Comment: I don't think it necessarily (if at all) indicates that. If anything, it has a flavor of "your reputation precedes you"/"I've heard about you" which can range from respectful to teaseful depending on non-verbals.